# How can I put a listener in other project to replicate nodes of that database in cloud functions Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to put a trigger in a other app database of an associate.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const config = {
  apiKey: "A----------------------------------------------A",
  authDomain: "****************.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*****************.firebaseio.com"
};
var adminAbi = require('firebase-admin');
const abiApp = adminAbi.initializeApp(config, 'abiApp');
const abiAppRef = functions.database.ref('messages')
//const abiDatabase = abiApp.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{now}');

exports.copyDatabase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{user_id}/{now}').onWrite(event =>{
    return;
});
```

But when I'm deploy the code to firebase I get this error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> TypeError: functions.database is not a function
>       at Object. (C:\Projects\functions\functions\index.js:25:34)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at C:\Users\victo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:21:11
>       at Object. (C:\Users\victo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:61:3)

I didn't found any oficial documentation of how to do this, and all I have found is useless in my case or I didn't now how to implement it corrrectly.
Thanks for the help in advice.

Comment: Is this a complete code sample?  Where's your `require('firebase-functions')`?

Comment: Also if you could edit your question state what exactly you're trying to accomplish, that would help.

Comment: It wasn't complete, I just added that part. Thanks for the tips, I'm new on stack overflow.